# Perform scroll in tableview, uipiceker and uidatepicker view class in ios

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview

I want to perform a scroll in the table view, picker view programmatically.

The program should scroll in the view based on the start point and the endpoint given. how this can be achieved. This code is used for testing the ui application.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can programmatically scroll a `UITableView` by using `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:`, e.g.:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:1];
[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:YES];
```

In a `UIPickerView` you use `selectRow:inComponent:animated:`, e.g.:

```
[pickerView selectRow:2 inComponent:0 animated:YES];
```

In a `UIDatePicker` you would use `setDate:animated:`, e.g.:

```
[datePicker setDate:[NSDate date] animated:YES];
```

Comment: paul, I want to perform this programmatically where i send only the coordinates to the function. I dont want to use indexpath.Think of the ui tester who want to perform a scroll by giving the coordianates alone he doesnt know abt the table information/table contents etc etc.. he should just perform a scroll in a table view. Mail your details to my mail id. where i can show my complete development code.